# Elixir - "this expression will fail with ArithmeticError" with integer multiplication

Tags: math, elixir

I'm getting this compile warning:

```
this expression will fail with ArithmeticError
```

from this code:

```
@seconds 300
@to_millis 1000

@seconds * @to_millis
```

I tried adding:

```
@seconds 300
@to_millis 1000

if is_integer(@seconds) and is_integer(@to_millis) do
   @seconds * @to_millis
end
```

is the problem that it could overflow? What is the correct way of handling this?

*** EDIT ***

In my actual code, these variables are coming from config files - something with the config is wrong and they are coming back `nil` so that is the problem. I think this can be closed since it's not an elixir problem

Comment: I can't reproduce "this expression will fail with ArithmeticError" from your code.

Comment: Could you copy/paste the whole module, because I can not reproduce the problem with having the if statement inside a function

Comment: I can only reproduce this if I use an attribute that doesn't exist or is assigned a non-interger. Maybe you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: thanks for the responses - this was actually a config issue. (edited original post)